# Cannot set "preAuthorizedApplications" object in new App registrations module through Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, adal.js

**Short Scenrario**: A muti tenant front end javascript (React.JS) Web Application calls a multi tenant ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebAPI from the browser.

*Authentication:*

1. ADAL.js in the front end app takes care of getting a token from either AzureAD1 or AzureAD2 or AzureAD3... when the User signs-in (based on the User's original Azure Active Directory).
2. The User gives consent to the front end Web App (*scope: Sign in and read user profile*) which is delegated to the WebAPI too. (*meaning the user does not need to consent to the WebAPI as well*)
3. The front end Web App calls the WebAPI with the bearer token to get the resources.

**Problem: I must automate the deployment of a new environment. And set the manifest file accordingly (It's a SaaS solution)**

1. In the manifest file I need to expose the WebAPI for the client application (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#expose-a-new-scope-through-the-ui)
2. Setting "knownClientApplications" is not enough (*due to previously described delegation*)
3. The new v2 endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) has a new App Registration feature. The old one is called "Legacy" now and will be deprecated starting May 2019.
4. In the Azure Portal need to expose the API and add the front end WebApp as an "Authorized cient applications".

[image: screendump]

This step will add a new object in the manifest file:

```
"preAuthorizedApplications": [
        {
            "appId": "guid",
            "permissionIds": [
                "guid"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

5. **But it's still not available throuh PowerShell!** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)

How can I add this "preAuthorizedApplications" section into the manifest file using Azure PowerShell? Why is it available in the portal but not in PS yet? It's the other way around usually...

**08-05-2019 Update based on the answer:**

I am getting the access token via a Service Principal:

```
$adTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"
$resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = "$ServicePrincipalId"
    client_secret = "$ServicePrincipalKey"
    resource      = "$resource"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $adTokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token
```

According to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs

The Service Principal should have at least Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, and most Application.ReadWrite.All privileges.

Should I ask our AAD admin to grant the below rights to the Service Principal?

[image: screendump]

**08-05-2019 Update 2: Service Principal has been granted with ALL of the highlighted rights above.**

**Attempt 1:**

*Step 1:* *getting an access_token via the Service Principal (Owner of the Api app to be updated)*

```
$adTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$(TenantId)/oauth2/token"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = "$(ServicePrincipalId)"
    client_secret = "$(ServicePrincipalKey)"
    resource      = "$resource"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $adTokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token
```

*Step 2: using this access_token, building up my PATCH request as per Md Farid Uddin Kiron's suggestion, and*

> Result: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

**09-05-2019 Update 3:**  After some kind and detailed explanation and guidance, I got this to work and getting HTTP 204 for my Postman request. Only thing left is to integrate this steps into my pipeline.

> **See accepted answer**. It works. If someone has the same issue,
>   please read the other answer from Md Farid Uddin Kiron.

Comment: Did you find another way to do that in Powershell without having to call directly the graph api ?

Comment: @TechWatching no, but simply because it was sufficient back then. Haven't tried the pure cmdlet/module way since I am not working on that project anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling directly the graph API (maybe you are in an azure pipeline using a Service Connection and don't have access to the credentials) you can do this :

```
$AppName = << WebApp >>
$preAuthorizedApplicationsAppId = <<GUID>>

# Get the application and delegated permission to pre-authorize
$appRegistration = Get-AzureADMSApplication -Filter "displayName eq '$AppName'"
$oauth2Permission = $appRegistration.Api.OAuth2PermissionScopes | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $AppName -and $_.Type -eq 'Admin'}

# Build a PreAuthorizedApplication object
$preAuthorizedApplication = New-Object 'Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication'
$preAuthorizedApplication.AppId = $preAuthorizedApplicationsAppId
$preAuthorizedApplication.DelegatedPermissionIds = @($oauth2Permission.Id)

$appRegistration.Api.PreAuthorizedApplications = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication]'
$appRegistration.Api.PreAuthorizedApplications.Add($preAuthorizedApplication)

# Update the Application object
Set-AzureADMSApplication -ObjectId $appRegistration.Id -Api $appRegistration.Api
```

This answer comes from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56214#issuecomment-638449476).

Comment: Wow, I like this! I mark this as an answer since it solves the issue by using the AzureAD module (it is GA, lovely!), in a very clean and elegant way! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, seems there is something faultiness exists in AzureAD powershell module. That not works for me too .

If you want to modify your `app manifest` using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) to add "preAuthorizedApplications" section, you can try the powershell script below.

I have tested on my side and it works for me.

In theory, I have called [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/?view=graph-rest-1.0) to modify the `app manifest` . If you have any further concerns, please feel free to let me know.

```
$AdAdminUserName = "<-your Azure ad admin username ->"

$AdAdminPass="<-your Azure ad admin password ->"

$AdAppObjId = "<-your app obj id->"

$AdPreAuthAppId = "<-the app that need to be pre authed ->"

$AdAppScopeId = "<-your app scope id->"

$tenantName = "<-your tenant name->"


$body=@{
    "grant_type"="password";
    "resource"="https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    "client_id"="1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";
    "username"=$AdAdminUserName;
    "password" = $AdAdminPass
}

$requrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+$tenantName+"/oauth2/token" 

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requrl -Method POST -Body $body 

$headers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $result.access_token)


$preAuthBody = "{`"api`": {`"preAuthorizedApplications`": [{`"appId`": `"" + $AdPreAuthAppId + "`",`"permissionIds`": [`"" + $AdAppScopeId + "`"]}]}}"

$requrl= "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/"+$AdAppObjId

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requrl -Method PATCH -Body  $preAuthBody  -Headers $headers
```

> **Note:** ROPC is not safe as Microsoft does not recommend to use that. It also does not allow to use MFA that is why it is little
>   dangerous.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron! Many thanks for your suggestion! I will be testing this soon. As a workaround currently I am adding myself (with an objectId) as an owner in the PS script when I create the apps in AAD, so I can make the necessary changes accordingly after deployment in the Azure Portal manually.What I noticed that the `$AdAppScopeId` (permissionIds) is different for all my apps. The `$AdPreAuthAppId` is clear, that's the object ID of the app. However I can't seem to find any documentation for scope id's. What I'm guessing now is that I can assign any valid GUID?

Comment: just found it. It's the id of the oauth2Permissions in my case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/preauthorizedapplication?view=graph-rest-beta#properties

Comment: Yeah you can. Let me know if you have any more concerned.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron! I have tested it finally. Unfortunatelly with an exception: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. Seems like the PATCH verb is not allowed?

Comment: Hi, it is weird...I tested the script above in 2 tenants and it works for them all. In fact , I am calling this Graph API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs  As you can see, only PATCH method is supported ... could you pls have a check ? If the API is called successfully it will reply 204: no content

Comment: Hi Md Farid Uddin Kiron! I have updated my question. Should that be OK for the PATCH request to go through with?

Comment: + the "Manage apps that this app creates or owns" was already set. But I am afraid that was not enough, hence the 405 response from Graph API. But I do not want to grant too many privileges either.

Comment: + updated my questions again with the attempts done later today

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to another reply.

Actually, in [`AzureADPreview`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.17) powershell module, there is a parameter `-PreAuthorizedApplications` for `Set-AzureADApplication`. But neither the cmdlet help nor the documentation page has been updated to detail all these, it was also mentioned [here](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2278/new-versions-of-the-azure-ad-powershell-modules-released).

[image]

I am not sure the parameter will work or not, per my test, I always get a bad request error. Even if I call the Azure AD Graph API, I get the same error. The command `Set-AzureADApplication` essentially calls the Azure AD Graph API, so if the parameter works, it will also work for the API. Also, in the AAD Graph doc, there is no such property. According to the test result, the parameter seems not to work currently. (not sure, if there is something wrong, please correct me)

Comment: Hi @JoyWang! Many thanks for your suggestions! I am using the MS Graph API `https://graph.windows.net/`  What I do from Azure Devops is that I am using the Service Principal of the service connection endpoint. And let it create all my apps in AzureAD with `New-AzureADApplication` and then `Set-AzureADApplication` if additional changes reuired. I will try out the Update apllication with the PATCH verb.

Comment: it's just sad that we don't know the correct syntax to use `PreAuthorizedApplications` due to the lacking docs

Comment: @ystvan yes, we need to wait for the update of the doc.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too using client_credentials type to get access_token to call that API even though I granted all Microsoft Graph API and AAD API application related permissions. It is really weird. 
However , using password flow to get access token under Azure AD admin account will be able to call this API successfully : 
[image]

**Update**

You could get your `client id` and `client secret` by below steps

1. Go to `azure portal` on `azure active directory` menu see the screen
   hot below:

[image]

2. Once you select `azure active directory` you would see `App
   registrations` click on that. Then select your application. See the below picture

[image]

3. On your apllication you would see the `client id`, `tenant id` and
   `client secret` which marked on the screen shot below:

[image]

If you still have any concern please feel free to share. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: As this way to get an access token is so secure , maybe involving  MFA will be a better way

Comment: Hi! Many thanks again for the update! I don't have much hopes for using our AAD admin, but if I do get some success: The username and password is clear, but What's the `client_id` and the `client_secret`? Isn't that (in plain English) I use when I authenticating an app (impersonating a user) so the app's username is the `client_id` and the app's password is the `client_secret`?

Comment: Yes, your Azure AD Application ID should be the client_id and its password should be the client_secret

Comment: And in your example of getting the access_token using the password flow: are you setting the highlighted  `client_id` and `client_secret` of the API you are about to update in the subsequent PATCH request?

Comment: No, the client_id and secret have nothing to do with the Azure AD App that you want to config in next API calling . The permission of access token which from password flow will based on the user's permission in Azure AD . So if you use Azure AD admin account to get this token , you will be able to perform all operations.

Comment: Thanks! Then may I ask what client_id and client_secret are you using? Where should I get them from? Whose id and secret should I be using in the grant_type = "password" call?

Comment: @ystvan You would get it from `azure portal` from your `application`

Comment: Apologies for being so noob and perhaps annoying, but which application?

Comment: The client_id and secret you can create an Azure AD App or use the value in your attempt 1 directly, they are the same thing. But the username and password , you should use an Azure AD account with permissions to modify Azure AD app config,and of course Azure ad admin account will with such permissions .And I did some test , a user assigned with "Cloud application administrator" role will has such permission too

Comment: @ystvan Please take a look on answer , I have updated for you. If you still have any issue feel free to comment and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

to resolve token issue I did like this(if you have az subscription owner, in this case you can get token which allows to update aad owned application properties without aad admin login and password). After az login by subscription owner:

```
$msGraphAccess = az account get-access-token --resource "https://graph.microsoft.com | 
ConvertFrom-Json
$accessToken = $msGraphAccess.accessToken

$headers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $accessToken)
```