# What is the correct syntax for Powershell AzureADPreview cmdlet Set-AzureADApplication "PreAuthorizedApplications" parameter?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

Following up another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991930/cannot-set-preauthorizedapplications-object-in-new-app-registrations-module-th), but from different point of view.

In [AzureADPreview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.17) powershell module, there is a parameter -PreAuthorizedApplications for Set-AzureADApplication. But neither the cmdlet help nor the documentation page has been updated to detail all these, it was also mentioned [here](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2278/new-versions-of-the-azure-ad-powershell-modules-released).

I was just wondering, that maybe someone happened to know how to use it and what's the syntax to set the list of [preAuthorizedApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/preauthorizedapplication?view=graph-rest-beta)  resource type?

[image: screendump]

Comment: As I mentioned in your another question, the command calls the azure ad graph, but in azure ad graph, the application object does not have the `preAuthorizedApplications` property, it is just existing in the MS graph. In one word, I think the parameter `-preAuthorizedApplications` in the command may be an empty shell. Besides, for the syntax, if it is existing, it should be like that of setting  `-RequiredResourceAccess`, the usage should be similar.

Comment: @JoyWang thank you for clearing things out! I updated my tags on the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize my comment：

The command `Set-AzureADApplication` essentially calls the Azure AD Graph API, but in Azure AD Graph API, the `application` object does not have the `preAuthorizedApplications` property, it is just existing in the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs#request-body), which means the feature is **not** implemented.

Some information you should know:

The old Azure AD Graph API appears to have been abandoned, Microsoft is no longer updating this content of AAD Graph regularly. You can find it in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api).

[image]

So you will find this is contradictory to the new feature `-preAuthorizedApplications` in the `AzureADPreview`. A solution for this is to let the AzureAD PowerShell to call the Microsoft Graph, someone has posted this idea in the azure feedback, you could vote it.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35362639-update-azuread-powershell-module-to-use-microsoft