# How to configure PreAuthorizedApplication for a new Azure AD application through Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have created a new Azure AD application through Powershell but I have a problem with the configuring PreAuthorizedApplication. The model includes 3 properties as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.graph.rbac.fluent.models.preauthorizedapplication?view=azure-dotnet). I don't use the extensions that is why I have assigned a value only for AppId and Permissions. But just to see if the reason for the error, I have assigned to the extensions also but the same result and always gets the same following error.

```
Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either 
specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value.
```

You can find my code below.

```
$preAuthorizedApplication = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication"
$preAuthorizedApplication.AppId = $myApiAppRegistrationResultAppId

$preAuthorizedApplicationPermissons = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplicationPermission" 
$preAuthorizedApplicationPermissons.AccessGrants = @($oauth2Permission.Id) # I have tried $oauth2Permission.Value also but nothing changed
$preAuthorizedApplicationPermissons.DirectAccessGrant = "True"
$preAuthorizedApplication.Permissions = $preAuthorizedApplicationPermissons

# Update the Application object
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $appRegistration.ObjectId -PreAuthorizedApplications @($preAuthorizedApplication)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because data type of `-PreAuthorizedApplications` is ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication] ``` and you are passing wrong data type in `Set-AzureADApplication` command. You can do something like the code below:

```
$preAuthorizedApplications = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication]'
$preAuthorizedApplications.Add($preAuthorizedApplication)
```

Comment: I have tried it before even I have changed my code like this but again the same error.

Comment: `$preAuthorizedApp.Permissions = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplicationPermission]
$preAuthorizedApp.Permissions.Add($preAuthorizedApplicationPermission)

$preAuthorizedApps = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PreAuthorizedApplication]
$preAuthorizedApps.Add($preAuthorizedApp)  

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $appRegistration.ObjectId -PreAuthorizedApplications $preAuthorizedApps`

Comment: Some configuration is getting missed. But, the right way to pass `-PreAuthorizedApplications` is the response.

Comment: I have found the information here that says that the future is not implemented yet. Have you tried to configure -preAuthoriedApplications ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053840/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-powershell-azureadpreview-cmdlet-set-azureadappli?noredirect=1&lq=1